# Why do people crowd baggage carousels?

Tags: airports

It is really very easy. Just stand a few feet away so that everybody will have enough space to view it and see when their luggage has arrived; when it has they can go up, grab it and be on their way. When you crowd around the thing as close as you possibly can, you restrict the area by which others can observe, thereby causing people needless delays. I have noticed that some airports have even put lines around baggage carousels, the point being obvious. But people still don't get it. Why?

Comment: Human behavior. We wish to be first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant about human behavior rather than a real question.

Comment: Because everybody standing a few feet back isn't a stable situation. Any person can improve their view by moving a little closer. But that blocks other people's view, so they have to move closer, and so on. It's the same deal with trees growing in the forest. If all the trees could just agree to be ten feet tall, they wouldn't need to spend so much energy growing tall. But any single tree could get more light by being eleven feet tall, so they all have to be. But then any single tree could get more light by being twelve feet tall, etc., so they all have to grow as tall as they can.

Comment: A real question would be something like "How can I efficiently get bags from a carousel?" Or "How can I deal with a situation where I have difficulties due to it being too crowded?". That being said, I haven't had any difficulties because of crowded carousels, possibly because I'm 6'4".

Comment: Seems like a classic [Tragedy Of The Commons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons) situation to me. One benefit of human stupidity here though is very often everyone no-one stands in the best spot right by where the bags first enter